# mobile layout-specifically iPhone zooming in on background image

Tags: ios, css, mobile, zooming

I recently put together a webpage for a client. 
www.kinektd.ca. 
Only when viewing on a mobile device the background banner images on the site get super zoomed in and pixelated.

Is there a mobile device media query I can add that ensures these images do not get zoomed in and pixelated on mobile devices?

Here is the css code that targets the background image;

```
.ts-home1-data-transferred{
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(../images/background/main02_2-1920x1200.jpg) ;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

}

Can I target mobile devices and include certain coding that will solve the zoom issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your issue in F12 developer tools using device mode set to iPhone 5. Which device are you seeing this issue on and are you aware of how to use media queries, in general?

Comment: I am having issues with the iPhone 6 device and yes I am aware of how to use media queries. I have targeted the specific div that I am having issues with and tried applying a media query, but I haven't managed to accomplish what I am after.